# Are the order topology on the natural numbers and the discrete topology equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

I'm currently trying to get a better understanding of topology and I've read that the order topology on $\mathbb Z$ is equivalent to the discrete topology, since every subset of $\mathbb Z$ is open.

But isn't this the same for $\mathbb N$? We have the same cardinality and if we take the power set of $\mathbb N$ element subset is open as well. And if it isn't, why not?

Also I came across the following example:

> $$\mathcal T_{\mathbb Z} := \{M\in \mathcal P(\mathbb Z): M = \emptyset \quad\text{or}\quad M = \mathbb Z\quad\text{or}\quad (-13 \in M \,\wedge 13 \notin M)\}$$

Doesn't this topology correspond to the discrete topology as well? I'm not really sure.

Comment: $\mathcal{T}_{\Bbb{Z}}$ is not discrete since $\{ 13 \}$ is not open. As for the first question, yes: order topology is the same as discrete topology.

Comment: Right, that's actually pretty obvious now that I think about it. Any other obvious properties this topology does have?

Comment: $\{ -13 \}$ is a dense open set, and is the unique open singleton.

Comment: But didn't you just say $\{13\}$ is not open? Never mind, I confused $\{-13\}$ and $\{13\}$

Comment: @Crostul Maybe you could post your first comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the order topology on $\mathbb N$ is discrete. (At first, I wanted to say this just follows from $\mathbb N\subset \mathbb Z$, but then I remembered that the subspace topology and order topology don't always agree!) A space is discrete if and only if every point is open. If $\mathcal O$ is a totally ordered set, what does it mean for $x\in \mathcal O$ to be open in the order topology? It just means that the set $\{x\}$ can be expressed as an open interval (possibly one-sided). Hence we need to write $\{x\}=(a,b)$ where $a\in \mathcal O\cup\{-\infty\}$ and $b\in \mathcal O\cup\{\infty\}$. This means that:

1. Either $x$ has a direct predecessor $a$ or $x$ is minimal in $\mathcal O$.
2. Either $x$ has a direct succcessor $b$ or $x$ is maximal in $\mathcal O$.